# Noun after "have been"

Tags: grammar, adjectives, nouns

Here is a part of [ACTIVE Skills for Reading 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1133308031), page 137:

> Humans have traditionally been omnivores, with a diet of both meat and vegetables. But lately it seems we've become a society of meat eaters.

Is "omnivores" correct here? I think it should be "omnivorous" because after *to be* verbs we use an adjective.

So is it a typo or different grammar structure?

Comment: Is that a link of Amazon page I see there?

Comment: The sentence is perfect. It doesn't need to be changed. "Have been" can be followed by a noun.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh Yes. I didn't find a pdf file for the book.

Comment: No worries. It is alright. Your sentence is self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> after *to be* verbs we use an adjective

No, not necessarily.  "To be" can be followed by a noun:

- I am an engineer.
- You are a genius.
- They are librarians.

There is nothing wrong with "humans are omnivores" or "humans have traditionally been omnivores".

Comment: Thanks. So why it is plural not singular? I mean "omnivore" instead of "omnivores".

Comment: Because _humans_ is plural, of course!

Comment: Since Humans is plural, Omnivores will follow the same pattern.

Comment: @KateBunting Is there any difference between "Humans have traditionally been omnivores" and "Humans have traditionally been omnivorous"?

Comment: Whether you choose to use a noun or an adjective makes no difference in the meaning.